# Ubuntu 16.04 The mbstring extension is missing

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, mbstring

I want to migrate my web server from unsupported version of ubuntu 12.10.
I installed 16.04 and installed apache2, php7, mysql and phpmyadmin.

When I want to use phpmyadmin I have error that mbstring missing.

In PHP.ini file, there is only to enable this extension for windows only.

When I install mbstring package, then when I reload phpmyadmin page, I get blank page without any error.

I installed following packages:

```
apache2, php, libapache2-mod-php, php-mysql, php-mbstring, php7.0-mbstring, mysql-server, phpmyadmin
```

When i uninstall mbstring packages, after phpmyadmin reload I see mbstring extension error...

What to do? I spent two days to fix this but have been unsuccessful...
Thanks

Comment: Here's solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/772397/mbstring-is-missing-for-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thanks Deepak  after i run `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext libapache2-mod-php7.0` phpmyadmin was loaded normally.

Comment: see the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035220/opensuse-phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing/44944076#44944076

Answer (score 1):

After you have installed the php7.0-mbstring module, you'll need to restart apache2 for it to take effect:  `sudo apachectl graceful`

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way (for me) to correct it... and it's fairly simple :)

Just add "`universe`" on the `xenial-updates`.

```
# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main
deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe
```

to do that, just

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

and then close all the windows, except the ones with `xenial-updates` where you add `universe` at the end of the line!

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do this:

`sudo add-apt-repository universe`

On older versions of Ubuntu, you might have to add a full deb source line:

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"`

After adding the repositories, do `sudo apt-get update` to update the package list.

Answer (score 0):

1. check installed modules using;
       php -m
   in here you couldn't see mbstring module
2. Then check the php version
       php -v
3. Then install module using following command
       php5.6-mbstring
4. Restart the apache server
       service apache2 restart

finally thats work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem from this post.
1-Install mbstring module according to your php version
$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
2-Install libapache2-mod module according your php version
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.2
3-Restart your apache2 services
sudo service apache2 restart

Ressource Link

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/install+mbstring+php+7.2+ubuntu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).